# Making a basic tally counter in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, counter

I am having difficulty in making simple tally counter application. I have put the codes but when i hit "run simulation", it always gives error message. can anyone help me find my mistake? thank you.

my codes are like below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter: Int!
    @IBOutlet weak var Display: UILabel!

    func updateDisplay() {
        Display.text = String(counter)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        counter = 0
        updateDisplay()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func PlusButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        counter = counter + 1
        updateDisplay()
    }

    @IBAction func MinusButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        counter = counter - 1
        updateDisplay()
    }

    @IBAction func ClearButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        counter = 0
        updateDisplay()
    }
}
```

here is the appearance in the Xcode
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10204747519271053&set=pcb.10204747520111074&type=1&theater

here is the error message when i hit run simulation
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10204747519351055&set=pcb.10204747520111074&type=1&theater

Comment: What error it gives and at which line?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10204747519351055&set=pcb.10204747520111074&type=1&theater it doesnt show any "!" signs but when i hit "run simulation", it doesnt want to work.

Comment: any place where I could see the project files? Github?

Comment: You can use this to share image: http://imgur.com/

Comment: thank you. this is the App appearance http://i.imgur.com/PHjbfCi.pngand this is the error appearance http://i.imgur.com/4HHnobE.png

Comment: @JinshuLiao your code works. It must be something with your IBoutlet or your IBActions. I made a test project and connected things properly and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine but I think you have problem with layOut connection so check it again and it should be like this:

For `Display` label:

[image]

For `PlusButton` :

[image]

For `MinusButton`:

[image]

And For `ClearButton`:

[image]

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08625518315597254515) sample project for more Info.